# Convert MP4 file in PAL standard video (720×576[785 × 576]) to 720×576 using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop, resolution, aspect-ratio

I have a video file in MP4 format which supposedly has a 720×576 resolution yet is 786 × 576 according to the Finder on Mac:

[image]

As part of this discussion here it's been pointed out to me that this may be because the file is PAL standard video, according to which this is the expected behaviour. I'd like to change this using ffmpeg so that the file actually is no longer PAL standard video but always only 720 pixels in width.

To do so, I've been pointed to this [question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20871/how-do-i-convert-anamorphic-hdv-video-to-normal-h-264-video-with-ffmpeg-how-to) to find the corresponding ffmpeg command. Yet when I try to run `ffmpeg -i weird_video.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1" -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 80k -ac 1 -movflags +faststart h-264-out.mp4`, I get an error message as the actual width of the video seems to be 785 and not 786 pixels as indicated by finder:

```
ffmpeg -i weird_video.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1" -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 80k -ac 1 -movflags +faststart h-264-out.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_9 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'weird_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 585 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x576 [SAR 131:120 DAR 131:96], 577 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fd77e00b600] width not divisible by 2 (785x576)
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x7fd77e00ce00] Qavg: 63846.375
[aac @ 0x7fd77e00ce00] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

When I run `ffmpeg -i <myvideo>` I get the following:

```
ffmpeg -i weird_video.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_9 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'weird_video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:00:12.27, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 585 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x576 [SAR 131:120 DAR 131:96], 577 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
At least one output file must be specified
```

I opened the video in the video editor Shotcut and there the width is given as 785 and not 786, which is in line with why ffmpeg fails:

[image]

My question hence is whether there is a way of converting the video with ffmpeg despite its weird width of 785 pixels?

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you play the video does it look normal? Try several players (QuickTime, VLC, etc). The player should resize it to 786×576 according to the Sample Aspect Ratio (SAR).

Comment: I've tried both QuickTime and VLC, they both resize the video to the actual size it seems, as it doesn't look distorted. The issue is that I am trying to do some further automated processing with these files and for this the incorrect information from the MP4 container seems to be used instead of the SAR, which then results in an incorrect output. Hence, I'd like to simply crop the video using ffmpeg to actually be 720×576 instead of 786×576.

Comment: These appear to be captures of PAL standard video. In which case, the data is correct. The stored resolution is 720 pixels per row but the display resolution is 768 pixels. It's not *supposed* to be presented as 720x576. See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/20871/

Comment: Many thanks for your response and the link! I've tried to use the command described there but this fails due to the fact that the width of the video appear to actually be 785 and not 786 pixels. I've updated my question to reflect this development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert non-square pixels to square pixels and crop to desired width:

```
ffmpeg -i weird_video.mp4 -vf "scale=iw*sar:ih,crop=720:ih,setsar=1" -crf 28 -c:a aac -b:a 80k -ac 1 -movflags +faststart h-264-out.mp4
```

See the [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), and [setsar](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setdar_002c-setsar) filter documentation for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This works insofar as the command runs, but instead of creating an MP4 video with the dimensions 720x576 it simply "downsizes" the video to 784x576? Is there something else I'm overlooking here?

Comment: @user149823 I mistakenly assumed you wanted square pixels while preserving the aspect. But now it is not clear how you want to handle the aspect change. Perhaps you are looking to simply force it while disregarding aspect: `-vf scale=iw:ih,setsar=1`

Comment: Ideally, what I'd like to do is crop the width to the left and to the right. That is, take the 720x576 starting from the center and crop the rest. The command you mentioned will scale the video, so it gets a bit stretched, but I'd prefer to simply loose the "excess" 33 pixels to the very left and the 33 to the very right.

Comment: @user149823 You can add a simple crop to the command as shown in the updated answer.

Comment: This seems to work like a charm, thank you so much!